# What is the difference bewtween var = 55 and :var = 55 in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, variables, symbols

I have just been watching [this video ion Symbols](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mBXGBbEbXZY&list=UUhs1F5WNk3wYkefIEVGxpLQ) in Ruby. In the video it seems to say that assigning a variable creates a symbol of the same name and points it the the respective object in the assignment.

I understand the difference between as String and a Symbol, in that strings create unique objects every time where as Symbols always reference the same object. However I am struggling to understand the difference between a Variable and a Symbol of the same name.

For example, how is:

> var = 55

Different from:

> :var = 55

Comment: `:var = 55` this is not valid Ruby expression.

Comment: You can't assign anything to a symbol. It makes as much sense as assigning `4 = 5`

Comment: So when in the video they are speaking about a symbol "Pointing to" an object what does that mean?

Comment: the video seems to sugges that when we create a variable we create a Symbol with a Name, an ID and an object that it points to is that correct?

Comment: @Cu1ture - This presentation helped me understand how ruby works behind the curtain: http://www.rubyinside.com/how-ruby-manages-memory-and-garbage-collection-3006.html. It explains very well how ruby manages its memory and what variables really are.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Ruby, you can store data in a Hash object... a Hash object is a collection of key value pairs

```
star_info = {:name = > "Johnny Depp", :birth_year => 1963, :birth_country = "USA" }
```

So the hash `star_info` has information about a movie star.  It's stored as keys (I'm using symbols but I didn't have to; it's common and efficient to do so) and values (the value related to this particular movie star for the related key).

To get the movie star's name I could do...

```
p star_info[:name]
=> "Johnny Depp"
```

So although the symbol doesn't actually "store" data intrinsically as a variable would, it can be used as a pointer to data stored in some Hash object.

To successfully retrieve data related to a symbol, you have to have BOTH the symbol (the key) and the Hash object (the object where the key/value pairs are stored).

EDIT

Just reviewed the video you referenced, it's a good video as far as it goes... what you might find confusing is that he refers to variables as "internal symbols" and it's not helpful to have a conceptual model based on that.  Symbols are representations... the symbol `:west` represents the concept `:west` and does not point to any other object.

Answer (score 1):

Symbol, as everything in Ruby, is an object, so it is a structure in the memory having methods, properties. And the **variable is a pointer (reference) to the object** - it stores the memory address, where the object lives.

So this `var = :something` is a valid syntax, it creates a Symbol instance `:something` and the variable `var` referencing (pointing) to this instance.

Learn more on symbols and reference on this article: [Ruby for Admins: Strings and Symbols](http://rubyforadmins.com/strings-and-symbols#symbols).